# No variants found for expo-gl-cpp in react-native android build

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

I am getting an error when i try to run react-native android build in android studio. it says:

```
Gradle sync failed: No variants found for ':expo-gl-cpp'. Check build files to ensure at least one variant exists. at:
                com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.AndroidModule.deliverModels(AndroidModule.kt:135)
```

Comment: hello @Osama Ahmed. i am facing a similar issue. I had to manually install `expo-gl-cpp` using `expo install expo-gl-cpp` although it is mentioned as dependency for  `expo-gl`. However the expo-gl java files are unable to import expo-gl-cpp. I am facing the following error. `/node_modules/expo-gl/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/gl/GLObject.java:3: error: package expo.modules.gl.cpp does not exist
import static expo.modules.gl.cpp.EXGL.*;` were you able to solve the issue you mentioned in your question